# Good logging strategy for AppHarbor and Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, ravendb, nlog, appharbor

I'm hosting an application on `AppHarbor` that uses `NLog` for logging. I've been trying the `Logentries` add-on, which is a nice service to pipe all the application logging through to and then view via their web interface. That has now come to the end of its free trial and I'd like to look at doing my own logging before paying for that service.

Because I'm using `AppHarbor`, they recommend not writing to the file system because it's wiped on each deploy and, when in flow, I do multiple deployments per day. I'm using `S3` for storing images anyway, so it seems natural to store logs there as well.

The problem I can see with that approach is that I would be firing log statements to a text file stored on `S3`, which I would need to append to. Once the site gets some traffic, there will be multiple, simultaneous calls to store log entries, which will probably end up locking the write mechanism. Is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of? Maybe batching the log entries somehow before sending them across? I'm using `Raven` as my database so may look at writing logs directly into `Raven` if there's no better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there are NLog targets for S3 or RavenDB, but there are a bunch or other options: http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Targets

Comment: Thanks @friism - looks like someone has written a RavenDB target: https://github.com/mswietlicki/NLog.RavenDb

Comment: But on closer inspection, this is the project that I was unable to get working previously, which is why I went with `Logentries` in the first place

Comment: And now I have got it working. I had two projects in my solution and had only added this package to the web project. Once I added it to the domain project as well it started working.